# Add padding to values of nested dictionary?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, for-loop

I have nested dictionary `events` that I would like to put into dataframe `df` so that I can later boxplot. The main problem I am facing is that the lists are of different lengths.

A smaller version of my actual dictionary looks like this:

```
events = { 'gene1' : {'n': [1, 2, 3], 't': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]},
           'gene2' : {'n': [1, 2, 3, 4], 't': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 'nan', 12]}}
```

I am trying to put this into a dataframe, but I am struggling with the different size lists. My code looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['gene', 'Normal', 'Tumor'])
for key, value in events.items():
       gene_df = pd.DataFrame({'gene':[key]*len(value['t']),
                               'Normal':value['n'],
                               'Tumor':value['t']})
       df = df.append(gene_df)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: arrays must all be same length
```

I saw other questions with solutions of padding lists with `nan`, but I'm not sure how to apply that to the inner dictionary values of my nested dictionary.

The wanted output would look something like this:

```
In []: df                                                                      
Out[]: 
    gene Normal Tumor
0  gene1      1     4
1  gene1      2     5
2  gene1      3     6
3  gene1    nan     7
4  gene1    nan     8
5  gene1    nan     9
6  gene1    nan    10
7  gene1    nan   nan
8  gene1    nan   nan
0  gene2      1     5
1  gene2      2     6
2  gene2      3     7
3  gene2      4     8
4  gene2    nan     9
5  gene2    nan    10
6  gene2    nan    11
7  gene2    nan   nan
8  gene2    nan    12
```

Suggestions?

Comment: whats the logic between the two nan rows after `t10` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the list in the dictionary to a `Series`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['gene', 'Normal', 'Tumor'])
for key, value in events.items():
    gene_df = pd.DataFrame({'gene':[key]*len(value['t']),
                               'Normal':pd.Series(value['n']),
                               'Tumor':pd.Series(value['t'])})
    df = df.append(gene_df)
df
```

Output:

```
   gene  Normal Tumor
0   gene1   1.0 4
1   gene1   2.0 5
2   gene1   3.0 6
3   gene1   NaN 7
4   gene1   NaN 8
5   gene1   NaN 9
6   gene1   NaN 10
0   gene2   1.0 5
1   gene2   2.0 6
2   gene2   3.0 7
3   gene2   4.0 8
4   gene2   NaN 9
5   gene2   NaN 10
6   gene2   NaN 11
7   gene2   NaN nan
8   gene2   NaN 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your data to make all lists within an event (or gene) the same length before using the dictionary in the DataFrame-Function:

```
for e in events.keys():
    maxlen = 0
    for col in events[e].keys():
        if len(events[e][col])>maxlen:maxlen=len(events[e][col])
    for col in events[e].keys():
        events[e][col]+=[None]*(maxlen-len(events[e][col]))
```

This will ensure that all your columns are of the same length, so you can use your code from above.

Answer (score 0):

pandas is like a table you need  that your lists will be the same length
you can add "nan" to the lists to make them the same size
or use other solution

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html